# Tensorflow resize failing with correct shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to reshape a tensor down from 2d to 1d, but when I try I get a really weird error that 2, 2, cannot be resized to 4. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_size = 2
y_size = 2
batch_size = 10

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, x_size, y_size))
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 1))

x = tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, x_size * y_size))
y = tf.layers.dense(x, 1)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_))

a = [[list(range(y_size)) for i in range(x_size)] for i in range(batch_size)]
b = [[1] for i in range(batch_size)]
sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: a, y_: b})
```

which gives me

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (10, 2, 2) for Tensor 'Reshape:0', which has shape '(10, 4)'
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because I was passing x into feed_dict, but I had overwritten x with the reshape. By replacing lines 12 and 13 with

```
nn = tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, x_size * y_size))
y = tf.layers.dense(nn, 1)
```

and adding

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

I was able to get it to work perfectly. Moral of the story, always keep your placeholders separate.

Comment: ah yeah, true dat... was curious of your implementation on reshaping and densing, didn't even think to look for the required initializer function. But thumbs up that you got the fix

Answer (score 0):

Your defined x tensor is actually rank 2 (3d) is set to [10, 2, 2]. So assuming you want to go to 2D then?

This is just a shot in the dark, personally haven't worked with reshape yet, but looking at the examples, there is a "flatten" parameter of -1?

So, copying from the [API doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape), this is capable:

```
# tensor 't' is [[[1, 1, 1],
#                 [2, 2, 2]],
#                [[3, 3, 3],
#                 [4, 4, 4]],
#                [[5, 5, 5],
#                 [6, 6, 6]]]    
# pass '[-1]' to flatten 't'
reshape(t, [-1]) ==> [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]

# -1 can also be used to infer the shape

# -1 is inferred to be 9:
reshape(t, [2, -1]) ==> [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                     [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]]
# -1 is inferred to be 2:
reshape(t, [-1, 9]) ==> [[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                     [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6]]
```

So, if wanting to go from [10, 2, 2] to [10, 4], shouldn't this theoretically work?

```
x = tf.reshape(x, [batch_size, -1])
```

Or if you actually want to go all the way down to 1D, then:

```
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1])
```

Comment: using -1 precomputes the size of the tensor, so when I run it it still has the identical error.